# How do I use numpy.where based on pixel alpha value?

Tags: python, image, numpy

I have two transparent RGBA images, each with shape (height, width, 4). I want to essentially flatten them like you would two layers in Photoshop, if img1 has alpha zero, the corresponding pixel of img2 should be used. Otherwise, the pixel of img1 "shows up in front" and is used.

I thought it would be as simple as:

`img = np.where(img1[:,:,3]==0,img1,img2)`

However, the issue here is that `img1[:,:,3]==0` has shape (height, width), and img1 and img2 have shape (height, width, 4), so they can't be broadcast together. I was trying to maybe use np.tile or np.repeat to force the boolean mask into the correct shape, but I'm having a lot of trouble getting it into the shape I want. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this answer your question?:

```
mask = np.expand_dims(img1[:,:,3]==0, axis=2).repeat(4, axis=2).astype('int')
img = img1 * (1-mask) + img2 * mask
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot about expand_dims, that really helps. Thank you!